# Why does capGetDriverDescription accept a buffer as a value type instead of a reference type?

Tags: vb.net, api, dll

Trying out some API programming, I encountered a problem with the capGetDriverDescription function of AVICAP32.dll:

```
Declare Function capGetDriverDescriptionA Lib "avicap32.dll" (ByVal wDriver As Short, _
    ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal cbName As Integer, ByVal lpszVer As String, _
    ByVal cbVer As Integer) As Boolean
```

As far as I know, the `lpszName` parameter is a buffer for getting the driver description, and I read somewhere that the buffer should be passed as a reference type (`ByRef` instead of `ByVal`), and of course it should be a reference because of storing the information I need after returning from the function. But in this function, it's a value type, and it works fine!
even I tried to change it to ByRef but the application didnt run!
What knowledge am I missing? How can this buffer store my information while it's being passed a value type?

This is how the code calls the function to get available webcams:

```
Private Sub LoadDeviceList()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim strName As String = Space(100)
    Dim strVer As String = Space(100)
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer = 0

    Do
        bReturn = capGetDriverDescriptionA(x, strName, 100, strVer, 100)
        If bReturn Then
            lst1.Items.Add(strName.Trim)
        End If
        x += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop Until bReturn = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying I don't know much about this subject (marshaling data can be a deep subject), but I think *[Default Marshaling for Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h(v=vs.71).aspx)* (MSDN) may help you. Scroll down to the part that says *Fixed-Length String Buffers*. According to this, when a string is marshaled to the API, even if passed byRef, it can't be modified by the callee.

I haven't tested, but according to the MSDN example, to get a value back from your function, the definition would become

```
Declare Function capGetDriverDescriptionA Lib "avicap32.dll" (ByVal wDriver As Short, _
ByVal lpszName As StringBuilder, ByVal cbName As Integer, ByVal lpszVer As String, _
ByVal cbVer As Integer) As Boolean
```

Changing `lpszName` from `String` to `StringBuilder`. Apparently `StringBuilder` will work as a buffer to get the string back from the function.

Then you would call your function like so,

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256)
capGetDriverDescription(Driver, sb, sb.Capacity + 1, ....
return sb.ToString()
```

I found a very similar question, *[How do I import and call unmanaged C dll with ANSI C string "char *" pointer string from VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428890/how-do-i-import-and-call-unmanaged-c-dll-with-ansi-string-char-pointer-strin)*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The example that I'm using, doesn't use any StringBuilder. It just use normal string in the function as I have pasted in my question. this example also uses normal string when calls the function. but still this code works! by the way, where I should start learning working with dlls?

Comment: Yeah, it will work with the normal string, you just need to use the StringBuilder to get the result back. I'm not sure if there is any one place to learn about this stuff, (other than Stack Overflow), but http://pinvoke.net/ is a great site for looking up the .NET definitions of popular functions and data structures.

Comment: I edited my question and posted how the code is calling the function there is no string builder :(