# Why ByRef gives exception while passing to unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, interop, unmanaged

This is my C++ unmanaged dll code.

```
void Only(char *a)
{
    *a++ = 'p';
    *a++ = 'r';
    *a++ = 'a';
    *a++ = 'n';
    *a++ = 'i';
    *a++ = 0;
}
```

.def file is used for exporting symbols.

I have used Only function in VB.Net application as follows,

```
Declare Sub Only Lib "dllproj2.dll" Alias "Only" (b As StringBuilder)
....
Dim s As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
Only(s)
```

It works fine. But when I try to use b as ByRef as follows,

```
Declare Sub Only Lib "dllproj2.dll" Alias "Only" (ByRef b As StringBuilder)
```

It gives exception shown in image.

[image]

I do not understand why. Doesn't ByRef is more appropriate here?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to see how this could ever work reliably. How could the `StringBuilder` class possibly know how much storage the C++ function requires?

Comment: @JonathanPotter What should be solution to this? And how removing ByRef makes it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be `ByVal`. The function will not overwrite the reference to `StringBuilder` itself. It will rather update the content of the `StringBuilder`. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428890/how-do-i-import-and-call-unmanaged-c-dll-with-ansi-c-string-char-pointer-str) for a similar question.)