# Call unmanaged C DLL with char pointer with VB.NET

Tags: c, vb.net, char, marshalling

I've done a lot of research on how to properly call an unmanaged C DLL function that includes a char pointer to pass out as string to VB.NET, but I still encounter access violation exception with the following code

```
<DllImport("Sdk.dll")> _
Public Function Get_FileNameAt(ByVal pointer As IntPtr, ByVal index As UInt32, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal name As StringBuilder, ByVal capacity As UInt32) As Integer
End Function

Dim StrName As New StringBuilder(256)
Dim pointer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
Get_FileNameAt(pointer, 1, StrName, 256)
```

I've tried both with and without the  in Pinvoke

The C function delcaration

```
GoSensor_FileNameAt(void* pointer, unsigned __int32 index, char* name, unsigned __int32 capacity);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import and call unmanaged C dll with ANSI C string "char \*" pointer string from VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428890/how-do-i-import-and-call-unmanaged-c-dll-with-ansi-c-string-char-pointer-str)

Comment: For `char*` it should be `LPStr` since it is not Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Declare Function Get_FileNameAt Lib "Sdk.dll" (Byref pointer As IntPtr, ByVal index As UInt32, ByVal name As StringBuilder, ByVal capacity As UInt32) As Integer
End Function

Dim StrName As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)
'Dim pointer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero  (IntPtr.Zero should pass directly because it's read-only)
Get_FileNameAt(IntPtr.Zero, 1, StrName, 256)
```